# R - import data under format DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM (PerformanceAnalytics)

Tags: r, time-series, performanceanalytics

This is a sample of the data I have in excel :
(First column = time, second = increase/decrease in price of asset1 during the last 5 minutes, 3td = same for asset 2)

```
6-09-2013 10:05  0,0004922067    -0,0006188252 
6-09-2013 10:10  0,0001639882    -0,0010296140 
6-09-2013 10:15  -0,0001639613   0,0000936977 
6-09-2013 10:20  -       0,0011963360 
6-09-2013 10:25  -       -0,0008062020 
6-09-2013 10:30  -0,0023778288   -0,0002017131 
6-09-2013 10:35  0,0023834963    0,0005115900 
6-09-2013 10:40  -0,0004919646   -0,0011090786 
8-09-2013 17:55  FALSE   FALSE 
8-09-2013 18:00  0,0016914750    -0,0010922993
```

What I did until now :
1 -Export to csv.
2 -Import to R

```
t3 <- read.table('t3.csv', sep="," , header=F , row.names=NULL)
```

3 - When i type the command : t3. I have the following :

```
                V1              V2              V3
1  6-09-2013 10:05   0.0004922067   -0.0006188252 
2  6-09-2013 10:10   0.0001639882   -0.0010296140 
3  6-09-2013 10:15  -0.0001639613    0.0000936977 
4  6-09-2013 10:20            -      0.0011963360 
5  6-09-2013 10:25            -     -0.0008062020 
6  6-09-2013 10:30  -0.0023778288   -0.0002017131 
7  6-09-2013 10:35   0.0023834963    0.0005115900 
8  6-09-2013 10:40  -0.0004919646   -0.0011090786 
9  8-09-2013 17:55          FALSE           FALSE 
10 8-09-2013 18:00   0.0016914750   -0.0010922993
```

Now I don't know if it is normal to have 1 2 3 4... 10 in front of every row.

Also when I type  : start(t3). I have :

```
Error in hasTsp(x) : invalid time series parameters specified
```

Ideally, what I would like him to do is to use the first colum as a time serie.
I tried a few thinks I read here but without success. Can someone help me out ?

Many thanks !

Comment: 1- Yes it is normal to have index. It is called `rownames`. 2- `t3` is a `data.frame`, `hasTsp` only receives a `vector` or a `matrix`, so you probably want to pass it a column, for example, `hasTsp(t3$V1)`

Comment: PerformanceAnalytics-package uses xts-classed objects and it would make more sense to import as zoo or xts classed objects. Do a search on : `[r] import xts`

Comment: If you convert it, as you write above, from Excel to csv, why don’t you convert it to the the proper R date-format (%Y-%m-%d) in the first place ? You can even define this as your default format in Excel.

Answer (score 4):

R doesn't really know what to make of your first column; it doesn't realize that those are dates. If you want them to be evaluated as dates, try the lubridate package, and then do something like this:

```
library(lubridate)
t3$Time <- mdy_hm(t3$V1)
```

Now, you've got your first column in a date format and you can manipulate it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your data as a time series observed at irregular date-time points as follows:

```
require(zoo)
datetimes <- strptime(t3[,1], format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
x <- zoo(t3, datetimes)
start(x)
#[1] "2013-09-06 10:05:00 CEST"
```

Comment: or read it in like this: `library(zoo); colClasses <- c(NA, NA, "numeric", "numeric"); fmt <- "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M"; z <- read.zoo("t3.csv", sep = ",", index = 1:2, format = fmt, tz = "", dec = ",", colClasses = colClasses, na.strings = c("-", "FALSE"))`